# Pumping Lemma for irregular language, how to choose and divide the string

Tags: formal-languages, pumping-lemma

The language on the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ is $$L=\{ab^nab^{n+1} |n>0\}$$

so i have to take a string w = xyz:

what's the best string to choose such that $|w| > n$? and then what about the division?

like $ w=ab^nab^{n+1}$ is a correct option? Then how can I divide this into three pieces? My attempt:

$ x = ab^s $ with  $ 0 ≤ s ≤ n -1 $

$ y= b^ta $   with   $  0 < t ≤ n - t $

$ z = b^k $   with        $ 0 ≤ k < n - t - s $

Comment: You don't get to choose how to divide the string! You have to consider *all* possible divisions.

Comment: Yes but I can choose the string to divide, important is that it still belongs to the languages and that it is $ > n $. Right?

Comment: You really don't have much choice regarding the string $w$. It will have to be $ab^nab^{n+1}$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: Ok I got this. Then what about the division?

Comment: What about it? You have to consider *all* possible ways. I suggest taking a look at some worked-out examples. You can find many on the web. If you're still lost after that, I suggest asking your TA.

Comment: The fact is that i understand the examples and the explanations I read, but when it comes to do it by myself, i'm stuck. I'll try to solve this lack, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

w = ab<sup>n-1</sup>ab<sup>n</sup>.

We have to consider all the division xyz = w with |y| >= 1 and |xy| <= n. So

x = a<sup>p</sup>b<sup>r</sup>

y = a<sup>q</sup>b<sup>s</sup>

z = b<sup>t</sup>ab<sup>n</sup>

where:

- p + q = 1
- r > 0 implies p = 1
- q + s > 0
- r + s + t = n - 1

Let's now consider w' = xy<sup>0</sup>z=a<sup>p</sup>b<sup>r+t</sup>ab<sup>n</sup>. If x is the empty string, then w' is missing the initial 'a' (and maybe some b), so w' is not in L. Else if x is not empty, we know that y contains at least one occurrence of 'b', so w' can't be in the form ab<sup>n</sup>ab<sup>n+1</sup> and w' is not in L.

Comment: I got your process, even if probably I would have never managed to think about this solution. Thanks!